# NetworkX graph creating process from numpy array gets killed

Tags: python, networkx

I have a similarity (dense) matrix of shape 20K by 20K, with float type data.

When I run `graph = nx.from_numpy_array(similarity_matrix)`, my computer starts to eat RAM memory like crazy, more than 10GB... and the python process ends up being killed.

I thought that networkx was able to deal with graphs in the order of magnitude of a few millions of nodes...

Is there a way to improve my process?

Answer (score 1):

If the similarity matrix is fully connected (i.e., there's an edge between each pair of nodes), then the graph will have O(n^2) edges which is very memory-intensive.

If your similarity matrix has a lot of zeros, one solution to consider is using a sparse matrix representation which only stores the nonzero elements, dramatically reducing memory usage.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
sparse_similarity_matrix = csr_matrix(similarity_matrix)
graph = nx.from_numpy_matrix(sparse_similarity_matrix)
```